# After two keydown events sometimes the third one is not received

Tags: javascript

I am having a strange issue. I am using the following code to detect that a key is pressed. If more than one key is pressed then I perform certain action (it is not relevant). This works *most* of the time, but but certain  key combinations (in particular when I press three of them) one of the events is not firing.

If I press 'a', 's', 'd' (at the same time) it works perfectly, `65`, `83` and `86` get printed on the console. However if  I press  's', 'd', 'e', only two of the codes get printed and the third only appear only when I release all the keys (not that there's no logging on the `keyUp` event). This only happens with *certain* key combinations.

I am using Chrome  59.0.3071.86 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5. I tried also on Safari and it has the same issue.

```
window.onkeydown = onKeyDown;
window.onkeyup = onKeyUp;
var lastEvent;

function onKeyDown(e){
  if (lastEvent && lastEvent.type == e.type && lastEvent.keyCode == e.keyCode) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  // do stuff
  lastEvent = e;
}

function onKeyUp(e){

  if (lastEvent && lastEvent.type == e.type && lastEvent.keyCode == e.keyCode) {
    return;
  }
  // do stuff
  lastEvent = e;
}
```

Comment: depends on the keyboard!! I can get a,s,d,f,g,h for example, then nothing until I release one of those keys - read [about rollover key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be completely wrong here, but this sounds to me like a keyboard issue called ghosting. Modern gaming keyboards (for instance) overcome this issue by managing a buffer internally of keys that are pressed.

You can test if this is the case here: https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/KeyboardGhostingDemo.mspx